# loadMask is only covering the first part of the grid

Tags: extjs, loadmask

The initial loadMask covers the grid but I am still able to scroll while it is loading and it doesn't cover below the initial screen. I am looking for a way to either disable scrolling while loading the store, extend the loadMask so that it covers the whole grid panel including the scrollable content or have the loadMask stay in place even if the grid scrolls. I am targeting the grid for loadMask (the default).

[Scroll while loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1PQr.png)

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle sample?

Comment: What target you have given for loadmask ?

Comment: I am not familiar with creating fiddles @ArthurRubens and am mostly debugging code rather than creating it (I am a junior dev new to ext.js). I have found a work around where I can disable the grid while it is loading from the store but I was hoping to find a solution with loadMask because I would rather not have to disable the grid.